# Getting initializer error on ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller, initializer

I get the error: "Class 'ViewController' has no initializer".  I have narrowed down the problem to this function that is being called.  Does anyone see the problem?

```
let locationManager1: CLLocationManager // your location manager
    func addBoundry(loc: CLLocation)
    {
        if let loc: CLLocation! = locationManager1.location {
        let center: CLLocationCoordinate2D = loc!.coordinate
        let lat: CLLocationDegrees = center.latitude
        let long: CLLocationDegrees = center.longitude
        var points = [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,long),CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,long),CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,long),CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,long)]
        let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &points, count: points.count)

        mapView.addOverlay(polygon)

        } else {
            print("no location...")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+class+has+no+initializer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when assign property use optional.

```
 let locationManager1: CLLocationManager?
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say `let locationManager1: CLLocationManager`, you're declaring a property that *must not* be `nil`, but not actually assigning anything to it.

So, you either need to declare an `init` that ensures `locationManager1` is assigned exactly one value (it's a `let` constant, not a `var`, after all!) or initialize the property inline like:

```
let locationManager1 = CLLocationManager()
```